# jQuery UI slider animation not updating ui vValue

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

How to animate jQuery ui slider with auto updating value on page load.

When page is loading the should animate from left to right than back the problem is value is not updating when slider start to animate

```
<!doctype html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <title></title>
            <link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">

        </head>
        <body>

            <p>
                <label for="amount">Minimum number of bedrooms:</label>
                <input type="text" id="amount" readonly style="border:0; color:#f6931f; font-weight:bold;">
            </p>
            <div id="slider-range-max"></div>
            <!-- Scripts -->
            <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
            <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
            <script>
            $(function() {
            $( "#slider-range-max" ).slider({
            range: "max",
            min: 0,
            max: 10000,
            step: 100,
            value: 0,
            animate: true,
            slide: function( event, ui ) {
            $( "#amount" ).val( ui.value );
            },
            change: function( event, ui ) {
            $( "#amount" ).val( ui.value );
            }
            });
            $( "#amount" ).val( $( "#slider-range-max" ).slider( "value" ) );
            $('.ui-slider-handle').animate({
                left: '0%'
            }, 1500, 'linear').animate({
                left: '50%'
            }, 1200, 'linear').animate({
                left: '40%'
            }, 1300, 'linear');
            });

            </script>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to sync the value changes during initial animation to the amount input you can use animation's step event and now value. You will need to do something similar in the slide event if you want amount to change at each animation step when a user changes the value.

```
$(function() {
    var maxValue = 10000;

    $( "#slider-range-max" ).slider({
      range: "max",
      min: 0,
      max: maxValue,
      step: 100,
      value: 0,
      animate: true,
      slide: function( event, ui ) {
        $( "#amount" ).val( ui.value );
      },
      change: function( event, ui ) {
        $( "#amount" ).val( ui.value );
      }
    });

    $( "#amount" ).val( $( "#slider-range-max" ).slider( "value" ) );

    $('.ui-slider-handle')
      .animate({ left: '0%' }, 
      { 
        duration: 1500, 
        easing: 'linear', 
        step: function (now) { 
          if (now <= 0)
            return;

          $("#amount").val(Math.round((now / 100) * maxValue));
        }
      })
      .animate({ left: '50%' }, 
      { 
        duration: 1200, 
        easing: 'linear', 
        step: function (now) { 
          if (now <= 0)
            return;

          $("#amount").val(Math.round((now / 100) * maxValue));
        }
      })
      .animate({ left: '40%' }, 
      { 
        duration: 1300, 
        easing: 'linear', 
        step: function (now) { 
          if (now <= 0)
            return;

          $("#amount").val(Math.round((now / 100) * maxValue));
        }
      });
  });
});
```

Comment: One more question how to display value inside or above of ui handler like in this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/pxfunc/6hyVP/10/

Answer (score 0):

To put the value inside of the slider, pretty much follow the jsfiddle, except also put the .ui-slider-handle text update inside of the initial animations:

```
$(function() {
    var maxValue = 10000;

    $( "#slider-range-max" ).slider({
      range: "max",
      min: 0,
      max: maxValue,
      step: 100,
      value: 0,
      animate: true,
      slide: function( event, ui ) {
        $( "#amount" ).val( ui.value );

        $(this).find('.ui-slider-handle').text(ui.value);
      },
      change: function( event, ui ) {
        $( "#amount" ).val( ui.value );
      }
    });

    $( "#amount" ).val( $( "#slider-range-max" ).slider( "value" ) );

    $('.ui-slider-handle')
      .animate({ left: '0%' }, 
      { 
        duration: 1500, 
        easing: 'linear', 
        step: function (now) { 
          if (now <= 0)
          return;

          var currentVal = Math.round((now / 100) * maxValue));

          $("#amount").val(currentVal);
          $(this).text(currentVal);
        }
      })
      .animate({ left: '50%' }, 
      { 
        duration: 1200, 
        easing: 'linear', 
        step: function (now) { 
          if (now <= 0)
            return;

          var currentVal = Math.round((now / 100) * maxValue));

          $("#amount").val(currentVal);
          $(this).text(currentVal);
        }
      })
      .animate({ left: '40%' }, 
      { 
        duration: 1300, 
        easing: 'linear', 
        step: function (now) { 
          if (now <= 0)
            return;

          var currentVal = Math.round((now / 100) * maxValue));

          $("#amount").val(currentVal);
          $(this).text(currentVal);
        }
      });
```

Comment: Have a one problem more range slider background should be white and when page loading and animation start range slider background should change color from left to right now its only one background color !!!. When animation finished and you grab the handler its normal range slider got it two backgrounds color here is a jsbin link http://jsbin.com/jegijorujo/4/edit